# Git commit Issue

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm working with git for commit my branch.
I have this problem pushing on git:

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Counting objects: 117, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
Writing objects: 100% (29/29), 2.79 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 29 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (17/17)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
remote: ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer
remote: Suggestion for commit message:
remote: Merge branch 'master' of ssh://s3.testing.com:29418/testing into m
asoud
remote:
remote: Change-Id: I12be02f75b42c4304591835dffe8d7e8aa01f761
remote:
remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
remote:   gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 me@s3.testing.com:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
remote:
remote:
To ssh://me@s3.testing.com:29418/telewebion
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (missing Change-Id in commit messag
e footer)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://me@s3.testing.com:29418/
testing'
```

I tried These things too:

```
 scp -p -P 29418 username@your_gerrit_address:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/
```

and

```
git rebase masoud -i
```

and

```
git commit --amend
```

but I still get the same error.

Comment: Your git repository has stricter rules than the default.  You must conform to them in order to push.  Read all lines starting with "remote:" very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Change-Id` is missing. Examine your log message and make sure the `Change-Id` is the last line of your commit message.

If you have copied to commit-msg hook, as you mentioned, and have done the `git commit --amend` the `Change-Id` should now be present in you commit message.

Answer (score 1):

You try to push a merge commit. These are not modified by the gerrit commit msg hook. However, the error message already suggests a valid ChangeId to use.

```
remote: Suggestion for commit message:
remote: Merge branch 'master' of ssh://s3.testing.com:29418/testing into m
asoud
remote:
remote: Change-Id: I12be02f75b42c4304591835dffe8d7e8aa01f761
```

So, simple do a

```
git commit --amend
```

and insert the `Change-Id` above as last line in the commit message.

Answer (score 0):

see line

```
remote: Merge branch 'master' of ssh://s3.testing.com:29418/testing into m
```

asoud

It indicates that there is a merge commit. Do a show log and do a soft reset on change id before this merge commit.